# Problem with generic extending some class

Tags: typescript

Why do I get errors in `e4`, `e5`, `e6`? All of them match `SomeClass` type so they have to match generic `RES`.

```js
class SomeClass {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: boolean;
}

class ChildOfSomeClass extends SomeClass {}

const someFunc1 = <RES extends SomeClass>() => {
  const e1: SomeClass = { a: "aaa", b: 123, c: true }; // ok
  const e2: SomeClass = new SomeClass(); // ok
  const e3: SomeClass = new ChildOfSomeClass(); // ok

  // Type '{ a: string; b: number; c: true; }' is not assignable to type 'RES'.ts(2322)
  const e4: RES = { a: "aaa", b: 123, c: true };

  // Type 'SomeClass' is not assignable to type 'RES'.ts(2322)
  const e5: RES = new SomeClass();

  // Type 'ChildOfSomeClass' is not assignable to type 'RES'.ts(2322)
  const e6: RES = new ChildOfSomeClass();
};
```

I eventually want `someFunc1` to return `RES | Promise<RES>` but for the sake of the example, I simplified it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RES extends SomeClass` means that the set of values described by type `RES` is a *subset* of the set of values described by type `SomeClass`. Imagine the following scenario:

```
class MyRES extends SomeClass {
   d: string;
}
```

This satisfies the condition `RES extends SomeClass`, however in none of the constructor cases you've provided do you assign `d`.

There are many ways to approach this problem, and the "correct" solution will depend on what exactly you're trying to accomplish with this method. For example, one solution would be to make your method take some constructor or converter method to create a `RES` from the known existing properties of `SomeClass`:

```
const someFunc1 = <RES extends SomeClass>(toRes: (SomeClass) => RES) => {
  const e: RES = toRes({ a: "aaa", b: 123, c: true }); // ok
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `RES` *extends* `SomeClass`. Imagine the following:

```
class SomeClass {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: boolean;
}

class ChildOfSomeClass extends SomeClass {}

class OtherChild extends SomeClass { d: string }
```

And imagine that `RES` is `OtherChild` (which does extend `SomeClass`) your code would then look like:

```
const someFunc1 = () => {
  const e1: SomeClass = { a: "aaa", b: 123, c: true }; // ok
  const e2: SomeClass = new SomeClass(); // ok
  const e3: SomeClass = new ChildOfSomeClass(); // ok


  const e4: OtherChild = { a: "aaa", b: 123, c: true };  // Not OK, OtherChild needs d

  // Downcasting SomeClass to OtherChild is not ok
  const e5: OtherChild = new SomeClass(); 

  const e6: OtherChild = new ChildOfSomeClass(); //This is especially not OK
};
```

You could solve this by just using `SomeClass` and then passing any child object will be ok.